# Is the login for the Minecraft pocket edition the same as that for the computer edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought my son a Galaxy Note 3 and downloaded the Minecraft Pocket Edition app. But the login for his computer is not recognized by the Pocket Edition. Can he use his PC login credentials for the Pocket Edition or are they separate?

Comment: I didn't even think PC & PE Edition were related.

Comment: Just make sure it is a Mojang account and not a Minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

Pocket Edition does not even have a login system required to play the game.

The *Realms Alpha* login under the options menu, however, *is* the same as on your computer, provided you login to Minecraft on the PC with a Mojang account (login with your email address).

Comment: Well it (the pocket edition on Android) prompted me for an email address and prompted me for a user name.

Comment: @DL You're choosing your username for Minecraft PE Realms, and this is permanent, so choose carefully.